# In Titanium, how can I prevent a ListView row from appearing selected when touching a child element of that row?

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

Using Appcelerator Titanium Studio, I have a ListView with a custom template for rows. The custom template has several child templates, the most relevant being an ImageView representing a checkbox. When this checkbox image is clicked, an event is triggered; however, this event cancels the bubbling of the click event.

My problem is that the row shows a selection style when the checkbox image is clicked. The selection style remains, probably because of the canceled event bubbling.

The question: How can I prevent the row from displaying the selection style when the checkbox image is clicked? I've tried setting the selection style on the row, like this:

```
"selectionStyle": Titanium.UI.iPhone.ListViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
```

Unfortunately, this solution prevents the rest of the row from looking selected when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can set [bubbleParent](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-bubbleParent) of imageView to not bubble it's parent while clicking.